# What policy required to renew database lease?

Tags: spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

I run a local vault dev server (v0.10.1) and use Approle as auth method. I create a renewable MongoDB secret engine, and then assign a policy to created Approle which grants all capabilities to path `secret/bootstrap`, `secret/application`, `database/creds/readwrite*` and `sys/leases/*`.

Using `spring-cloud-vault`(v1.1.0), it could properly gets username/password of MongoDB after launched. But when the lease is reaching its ttl and spring-cloud-vault tries to renew it, I got the following exception:

```
2018-05-03 20:16:12.369  WARN 2921 --- [g-Cloud-Vault-1] LeaseEventPublisher$LoggingErrorListener : [RequestedSecret [path='database/creds/readwrite', mode=RENEW]] Lease [leaseId='database/creds/readwrite/200fad65-2165-9da4-206f-bb65c93cfdaa', leaseDuration=300, renewable=true] Status 403: permission denied
org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 403: permission denied
    at org.springframework.vault.client.VaultResponses.buildException(VaultResponses.java:62) ~[spring-vault-core-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.doWithSession(VaultTemplate.java:321) ~[spring-vault-core-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer.renew(SecretLeaseContainer.java:519) ~[spring-vault-core-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer.doRenewLease(SecretLeaseContainer.java:487) ~[spring-vault-core-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer$1.renewLease(SecretLeaseContainer.java:437) [spring-vault-core-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer$LeaseRenewalScheduler$1.run(SecretLeaseContainer.java:678) [spring-vault-core-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
```

May I know what I missed for the case please?

UPDATE:
I changed the path from `sys/leases/*` to `sys/*` and then seems everything works fine. So I still want to know what paths in `sys` besides `sys/leases/*` are necessary for the case.

Comment: HI, I have this exact problem, the difference being even changing my path to sys/* doesn't allow for non-root renewal. I have vault version 0.10.4 on the server and spring-cloud-vault-config-databases v 2.0.1.RELEASE. I can renew via the client with a non-root token though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your update. Seems we'd better create an issue in git repo of these projects. I'm waiting for really a long time, but got no answers yet...

Comment: I created an issue with Vault and Spring, the later ongoing.

Comment: Could you share the link of the issue please?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/255

Comment: Thanks a lot for your info. I can confirm that the error has gone with Spring vault ver.2.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (both with Spring boot ver.2.0.6.RELEASE and Spring cloud ver. Finchley.SR1), but it occurs some other errors that spring vault seems cannot renew secret_id and lease. I'll summarize these and create another issue then.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, the problem itself seems be resolved in `spring-vault-core 2.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`, but there's still lease renewing problem seems not be resolved yet[Expired leases do are not rotated on secret renewal](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/issues/319).